# Start a new usable konsole terminal with a command

Tags: shortcuts, konsole

I'm trying to set a shortcut that starts a Konsole terminal, run the alsi command, and then return itself to being usable. I'm aware of the konsole -e command, but that doesn't make the terminal window usable, rather it just runs the command and quits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a script so you would call

```
konsole -e <script>.sh
```

And then in the script place

```
#!/bin/bash
<command>
exec bash
```

And that should keep you konsole open after words then just shortcut it

Comment: `konsole -e "command; exec bash"` might also work.